# Promises: how to return a promise which has a otherwise error handler

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using tableau js api and calling `worksheet.applyFilterAsync` & `workbook.changeParameterValueAsync` methods based on certain conditions. These methods have an otherwise error handler.

I am also in between the executing flow return my custom promise like

```
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true)
      });
```

the issue is when i am returning promise and not `changeParameterValueAsync` or `worksheet.applyFilterAsync` i am getting an error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).otherwise(function (err) {...')
```

looks like the promise i return does not have a otherwise error handler?

relevant code is as follows

```
  const applyStep = (step) => {
    if(step.step_type == 'filter') {
      return worksheet.applyFilterAsync(step.name, values, 'replace');
    } else if(step.step_type == 'parameter') {
      return workbook.changeParameterValueAsync(`${step.name}`, value);
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(true)
      });
    }
  };


  const applyFilters = (counter) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let filter = filters[counter];
      if(filter) {
        applyStep(filter).then(promiseTimeout(filter.delay)).then(() => resolve(applyFilters(++counter))).otherwise(function(err) {
          reject(err);
        });
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  };
```

I need the `otherwise` error handler to handle error returned by tableau api methods but it does not work in cases where i am returning my custom promise, may be because the promise i am returning does not have an otherwise error handler?

How can address this any help in fixing this will be really great, Thanks.

Comment: Is it really "otherwise"? In promises, error handling is usually done with `.catch()`.

Comment: @C14L Seems like it: https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#promise_class

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: After purging the Promise constructor anti-pattern, `return Promise.resolve(applyStep(filter)).then(...).then(...);` should get you out of trouble by recasting the tableau promise as a native promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [tableau docs](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#promise_class):

> otherwise(errback: Function)  Promise Registers a rejection handler. Shortcut for then(null, errback).

So in your code, you could do

```
applyStep(filter)
.then(promiseTimeout(filter.delay))
.then(() => resolve(applyFilters(++counter)))
.then(null, function(err) {
    reject(err);
});
```

That is instead of `.otherwise(err)` you can use `.then(null, err)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are currently mixing two different types of promises. The tableau [`Promise`](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm#promise_class) and the standard JavaScript [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). These two have different methods which currently results in issues. You can pass a tableau Promise to [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to convert it into a standard JavaScript Promise.

```
return Promise.resolve(worksheet.applyFilterAsync(step.name, values, 'replace'));
```

When working with the promise you now have to work with [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and [`finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) instead of `then()`, `otherwise()` and `always()`.